# Rails RSpec deleting item from collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I've been beating my head too long on this issue...

My Scenario:

> I have a Rails 4 app.  I am simply wrinting a spec for my `Subscription` model.

Here is the relation:

```
subscription (has_one subscriber, has_one batch)
  subscriber_id: int
  batch_id: int

subscriber (has_many subscriptions)
  id: int
  email_address: string
```

#### subscription_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Subscription do
  before :each do
    @subscriber = Subscriber.create(
        :id => 1,
        :email_address => 'some.subscriber@example.com'
    )
    @batch = Batch.create(
        :id => 1,
        :name => 'Test Batch'
    )
  end

  it 'subscribes a user to a report successfully' do
    @subscriber.subscribe_to! @batch.id
    expect(@subscriber.subscribed_to? @batch.id).to eq(true)
  end

  it 'unsubscribes a user from a report successfully' do
    @subscriber.subscriptions.create(:id => 1, :batch_id => @batch.id)
    expect(@subscriber.subscribed_to? @batch.id).to eq(true)

    @subscriber.unsubscribe_from! @batch.id
    expect(@subscriber.subscribed_to? @batch.id).to eq(false)
  end
end
```

My last spec is failing with this error:

```
Failure/Error: expect(@subscriber.subscribed_to? @batch.id).to eq(false)

   expected: false
        got: true
```

Since the first spec passes, I know that the `unsubscribe_from!` is the culprit, *not* the `subscribed_to?`.

#### Subscriber#subscribed_to?

```
def subscribed_to?
  subscriptions.each do |subscription|
    return true if subscription.batch.id == batch_id
  end
  return false
end
```

#### Subscriber#unsubscribe_from!

```
def unsubscribe_from!(batch_id)
  p subscriptions
  Subscription.where(:subscriber_id => self.id, :batch_id => batch_id).destroy_all
  p subscriptions
end
```

Why isn't this actually deleting?

I've also tried

```
subscriptions.each do |subscription|
  subscriptions.delete(subscription) if subscription.batch_id == batch_id
end
```

With the error: `"subscriber_id" cannot be NULL`, and couldn't get anywhere on that front so i tried the penultimate solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since the first spec passes, I know that the `unsubscribe_from!` is the culprit, *not* the `subscribed_to?`.

You sure about that?  You know one side of `subscribed_to?`, the side that returns true.  It seems that it returns true quite a bit actually, based on your failing test.  If we could see the code for it we could rule it out of course.

edit: Ok, so a couple things to try:

Use the associations you have to do some of the work for you, less error prone:

```
def unsubscribe_from!(batch_id)
  subscriptions.where(:batch_id => batch_id).destroy_all
end

def subscribed_to?(batch_id)
  subscriptions.where(:batch_id => batch_id).exists?
end
```

And sometimes when you mess w/associations you can reload the object to help alleviate any caching that may be taking place:

```
it 'unsubscribes a user from a report successfully' do
  @subscriber.subscriptions.create(:id => 1, :batch_id => @batch.id)
  expect(@subscriber.subscribed_to? @batch.id).to eq(true)

  @subscriber.unsubscribe_from! @batch.id
  expect(@subscriber.reload.subscribed_to? @batch.id).to eq(false)
end
```

Comment: I'm sure.. I did some testing via `rails c` and found that it's just not deleting the record from the collection.  I've edited my source and added `subscribed_to?`

Comment: WOOHOO!!  That did it!  Thanks so much.. i knew there was an easier way to do this.. i'd been beating my head way too long over this

Comment: hmmm... I just tried to do `expect(@subscriber.subscriptions.length).to eq(0)` (on the last line) and it says `got: 1`   Are you sure this actually deletes it?

Comment: though `expect(Subscription.all.length).to eq(0)` DOES work.. that's funky.

Comment: Make sure you reload, the `@subscriber` caches its relations.  In my example I called `reload` and used the return value, but `@subscriber` is still the same old instance.  If you want to reload and assert several things you'll need to do something like `@subscriber = @subscriber.reload`, then make your assertions.

Comment: ahh.. i missed that bit.  that's interesting.  works yet again.  :)  I'll remember `reload`.  Thank you sir.

Comment: just curious though.. won't the `reload` method simply return it to it's original state before the assignment?  rather than the result after `unsubscribe_from!` is called?

Comment: `reload` populates the object as if you just loaded it from the database, so it should contain its "current" data.  Active Record does so much magic sometimes you forget an instance of a record is just an object in memory, if you delete data out from underneath it, it doesn't know unless you tell it to reload itself or get a new instance.